# Adobe AIR CameraRoll can't select photo on Android 6.0

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I'm having some issues with uploading images with media promise as described [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/uploading-images-media-promise.html).

The problem is after updating the phone to new Android 6.0 the `Async` image never loads anymore, in the following code, listener is added to `eventSource` but `onMediaLoaded` never fires. Before the update everything worked perfectly:

```
private function imageSelected(event:MediaEvent):void {

    trace( "Media selected..." );
    var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
    dataSource = imagePromise.open();

    if( imagePromise.isAsync )
    {

        trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );

        var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;
        eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );

    }
    else
    {
        trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
        readMediaData();
    }


}
```

Among other permissions, I have these in the descriptor:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

i also tried to load the promise like this, but got exactly same result:

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
loader.loadFilePromise(imagePromise);
```

Comment: What target sdk are you using? Most likely this is related to the run time permissions added in 23 (i.e. 6.0) You could probably get around it by specifying an older target sdk.

Comment: Thank you Michael! This is the solution. After changing the target sdk to 22 it works perfectly again :)

Comment: Great! I'll add an answer with another method to get around the issue as well. Cheers

Comment: Also **File Reference** might have worked if just selecting saved photos from device's Photo Gallery folder (or SD card). No older runtimes or ANEs required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 6.0 (v23) they introduced runtime permissions where you have to ask the user for permission to access certain "dangerous" permissions.

The problem will be that Adobe haven't added this permission request to the media loading method you are using.

There are 2 ways around this, as I suggested in the comment, set your target sdk to be an older version. This will tell Android that your application doesn't support any of the 6.0+ features and should rely on the older permission model.

The other is to grab an ANE to request the required permissions when you need them. Eg you can use the Permissions ANE from us:

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Permissions

Use that method if you require any of the Android 6.0 features to be used in your app.